# Access - Data import best practices

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, ms-access-2007

this is a best practices question.

**The Task:**

I need to import a report to Access 2013.  The report can be generated as either a .csv file, or a .xlsx file. During the import process I need to:

1. Ignore lines of irrelevant data and import only the data in one section of the report. This *relevant* data will be in a proper
   table with table name, table header, and then records  below it.
2. Match columns (most likely by header) with existing data in my database.
3. Import matching columns to the proper matching columns, in the proper matching tables of the database, and type the data accordingly.
4. Generate custom Keys for imported records.

There are many ways to go about it, i'm just looking for a little input from the community as to what might be the most efficient way.  Speed of import is important, you can assume the report will have somewhere in the neighborhood of 50k records.

**Background on me:**

I am a very advanced programmer with some experience on VBA and very little experience within MSAccess.

**EDIT**

My data looks like this:

```
 Title Cell
 File Info Cell
 Time Date Cell

 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 Data1, Data 2
 ....(continues for around 800 rows)

 Second Table Title Cell
 Col1Title, Col2Title, ColTitle, Col4Title ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)    
 Data 3,    Data4,     Data 5,   Data6 ....(continues for around 50 columns)
 ...(Continues for around 1500 rows)
 End of CSV
```

I guess the big problem is how to extract just table 2 from the text file.  This seems to be preventing me from using SQL to query the data.  Can I select just the second table of the text file?

Comment: I used linked tables and append queries. They work pretty well.

Comment: Best? Don't know. For csv data, an import specification will get the data in the fastest, though given you only want a portion of it, I'd be picking you're best to read it a line at a time, to locate what it is you want. For .xlsx, I'd think you'll need to open it via create object, and hopefully you can locate the data via a named range, though if you do have to loop through cells for the table I doubt it would be that slow. Once you've found your data SQL is usually faster for manipulating/using data than using cursors and loops.

Answer (score 0):

Excactly, linked tables and append queries.  Or, load your data into a staging table (i.e., temp table) and append records from that (which presumably has everything).  So, you would append ONLY the records you need into your production table.

Comment: Thanks all,  I've been doing my research and given your responses this is what I see:

1.  Setting up a staging table seems like the easiest practice
2. I want to access the CSV data in such a way that I can use query to extract the data I want.  

Here is my big question:

   How do I identify the table I want within the CSV.  There is a lot of useless information at the top of the file, and the table I want (labeled "Report Fields" is underneath).  Given the current methods, I can't see hot to do that.

Comment: I've added an edit to help better explain the issues I'm running into with this method.